# How can I parse an AngularJS page with Nokogiri?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ruby, capybara

I'm using Nokogiri gem to parse a web page document.  However I'm trying to do it on a website that uses AngularJS (I believe) and when I load it into Nokogiri it isn't formatted as what I see when visiting the page in my browser.  How can I cause it to load as I would expect so I can parse it via css selectors?

Url: http://www.ukathletics.com/sport/m-footbl/roster/#/2015/Players/table

**Code**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'capybara-webkit'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'byebug'
require './ncaa_school_sites'
require './functions'

include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.block_unknown_urls
  NcaaSchoolSite.where(code: 'KYUN').order(:code).each do |school|
    config.allow_url("*#{school.website_url}")
  end
end

visit(school.roster_url)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(body)

byebug
roster_table = doc.css("div.player_table table")
headers      = retrieve_headers(roster_table.css("thead tr"))
process_player_rows(roster_table, headers, school,"tbody td",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you're using Capybara and then trying to parse the page with Nokogiri?  Using Capybara alone you can do things like things like

```
roster_table = page.find(:css, 'div.player_table table')
headers = roster_table.all(:css, 'thead tr')
```

etc...

Comment: I wasn't aware about that... thanks! I originally wasn't using capybara, but came across some pages that seemed like they weren't loading properly so that's why I ended up passing things through capybara.

Comment: Also, I tried the code you mentioned but I don't see where Capybara has loaded the document fully either. So I'm not getting back any results with your code.

Comment: @daveomcd It doesn't fully load the document -- it's querying it in the "browser" provided by capybara-webkit - When you say no results, do you mean in headers? or roster_table?  headers may return an empty array because finding no  results is valid for `#all` so it doesn't wait for results to appear.  You can make it wait for results (loaded via xhr requests, etc) to appear by giving it a count of things to find so  `headers = roster_table.all(:css, 'thead tr', minimum: 1)` for instance will wait a bit until there is at least one row in a thead element, and then return it.